# Optimal performance for many-to-many relationship table in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a time critical component in my database and I am trying to make the retrieval of this information as fast as possible. My question is how to best implement it. 
I am using Flask-SQLalchemy and I have a helper table for a many-to-many relationship. I though I should index this table, but I thought since primary keys are always indexed I could just add a primary key like this

```
category_selection = db.Table(
    'category_selection',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('category_id', db.String(1000), db.ForeignKey('SocArxivCategory.id')),
    # The combination of the two foreign keys should be unique, since no user can 
    # follow the same category twice.
    db.PrimaryKeyConstraint('user_id', 'category_id')
)
```

However, I never access this table through this primary key, so does this make any sense? So when should I use index=True and when does it make sense to add a primary key to such a helper table?

My underlying database is Postgresql and the helper table above is used as

```
selection = db.relationship('Category',
                            secondary=category_selection,
                            lazy='dynamic')
```

Comment: It makes sense. You'll enforce that no duplicate entries are entered (as you've noted) and the implicit index can be used to speed up access to the table when filtering by a single column only, or possibly when joining. And if it happens that you want to deassociate, you'll be using the pk.

Comment: thanks... is there any point still adding index=True to the individual columns?

Comment: I don't see why you should, since the index backing the pk can already handle queries filtered on just 1 column, but do test.